# Angular: Why is $watch being called?

Tags: angularjs, event-handling, watch

Any reason why a `$scope.$watch` would be called when the value it is watching for does not exist anywhere within the app?

As you can see below, no matter what string I assign for the *watchExpression* , the function runs ...

```
$scope.$watch( 'kwhefjkewgfweahhfwujad' , // a bunch of random letters
               function()
                  { console.log("it fired ... why?");
                  }
              ) ;
```

Firefox does not indicate any errors.

Comment: It's explained in the official documentation of $watch.

Comment: I am here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope ... but I do not see anything that suggests to me why it might be called ...

Comment: It says: *the listener is always called during the first $digest loop after it was registered*.

Comment: I'll have to look to see if I have any .digest() calls during the angular parsing phase ... I am certain I have them 'hidden' behind `if( ! $scope.$$phase){$scope.$digest());` such that they do not run during init phase ... thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$scope.$watch( 'kwhefjkewgfweahhfwujad', function(val) {
    if (val) {
        console.log("it fired ... why?");
    }
});
```

watchers are running with every digest cycle. as you are watching primitive value, attached to the scope, you need to verify that a new value exists (and has changed).

you could also do

```
$scope.$watch( 'kwhefjkewgfweahhfwujad', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
        console.log("it fired ... why?", newVal, oldVal);
    }
});
```

Comment: I did not mention that until about an hour ago I was not having the problem (I figured that that would just muddy up the question) ... I think though that this is a solution, even if it doesn't explain my unexpected change in behavior ... I'll have to just figure that on my own ... strange .. ... thanks, Shannon